SHA-1 Hashing brute force
import hashlib

# Prompt the user to enter the target SHA-1 hash
target_hash = input("Enter the target SHA-1 hash: ")

# Path to the dictionary file
dictionary_file = r'C:\Users\johnny\Documents\Security\src\wordlist.txt'

def dictionary_attack(target_hash, dictionary_file):
    with open(dictionary_file, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            word = line.strip()  
           
            word_hash = hashlib.sha1(word.encode()).hexdigest()
            
            if word_hash == target_hash:
                print(f"Found the original string: {word}")
                return word
    print("Could not find the original string in the dictionary.")
    return None

   
original_input = dictionary_attack(target_hash, dictionary_file)

I want to find the original word from the hash function. I can reverse it now by brute-force, but the problem is when the word is upperchar like "JoeJoe" or "j0ej0e" it's not found in the list.
But in the list there is "joejoe". How to convert it to uppercase, or there is a way to do it?

Hashing is case-sensitive, so either your dictionary has to include the uppercase variants, or your code has to check every possible permutation of capitalization... which would make your code run n*(2^length(n)) additional brute-force attempts

Yeah how do i check every possible permutation ;c

Why did you remove the case variations generator that you had in your earlier question and that already worked?

This function will do what you ask, but there are things to consider here.
First, as ipodtouch correctly mentioned, the number of permutations is exponential.  Your 6-letter word produces 2**6 or 64 results.  If your dictionary is non-trivial, this will take far too long.
Second, this is relatively advanced.  I use "range" to create the integers from 0 to 63, then I use the binary value to decide whether the letter should be lower or upper.  9, for example, is 001001, so I uppercase the 3rd and the 6th letter.
In this version, I use a list to collect the results.  In my first version, I used "yield", but that's even more advanced.
def permutecase(word):
    answers = []
    word = word.lower()
    for i in range(2**(len(word))):
        t = ""
        for j,c in enumerate(word):
            if 1<<j & i:
                t += c.upper()
            else:
                t += c
        answers.append(t)
    return answers

for s in permutecase('JoeJoe'):
    print(s)

Output:
joejoe
Joejoe
jOejoe
JOejoe
...
joEJOE
JoEJOE
jOEJOE
JOEJOE


Ah, barely beat me to the punch. I'm still upvoting your answer for outlining the functionality into another function; much easier for a beginner to read.

Meh, don't worry about being too advanced. I'm quite confident they successfully used itertools for this here (similar question, deleted three minutes before this one was posted, by user "johnny rowdy" while this user is "jr." and has C:\Users\johnny)

Beat me too. But good to see consensus.

@mckenzm And the OP beat all of you :-P ... Their earlier program even already successfully found "ThaiLanD".

Hashing is case-sensitive, so either your dictionary has to include the uppercase variants, or your code has to check every possible permutation of capitalization... which would make your code run n * (2 ^ length(n)) additional brute-force attempts.
If you're fine with this cost, you can do something like
for line in file:
    word = line.strip()  
    
    for mask in range(2 ** len(word)):
        test_word = str([x.upper() if ((1 << i) & mask != 0) else x for i,x in enumerate(string)])

        word_hash = hashlib.sha1(test_word.encode()).hexdigest()
            
        if word_hash == target_hash:
            print(f"Found the original string: {word}")
            return word


The basic logic is that you can represent all permutations of capitalization as a binary number. The string abc for example would have 8 permutations:
abc => 000
Abc => 001
aBc => 010 
ABc => 011
abC => 100
AbC => 101
aBC => 110
ABC => 111

We then loop through the range of all permutations and create a new string, with the capitalization of each letter based on the permutation.

This is by no means the most efficient way of doing this. For example, you could skip characters that don't have a "capitalized" form, like numbers or symbols.

I try to find the original word from "d54cc1fe76f518630a0939d2fc1723c44e8a5f78"
which is "ThaiLanD" it's doesn't found in list ;c

Sorry to be dumb i just learning this course ;c

@jr. start with MUCH smaller words of 3 characters. You do not need a permutation of the letters at least, so you are caplitalising characters, start by doing this on paper. It is very much like a truth table as letters are either upper or lower. 3 character words can be masked with an octal, extend this.

You do not have to use a bit mask, but think of how you would you would create every possible test case for short words at first. Numbers non-maskable don't  care values.
3 character words such as "air".
air  000
aiR  001
aIr  010
aIR  011
Air  100
AiR  101
AIr  110
AIR  111

I am not saying to use a mask, but think of it this way.

can i just convert every thing in the list to uppercase like a "joejoe"
Joejoe
jOejoe
like this ?

You can extend this to any length, given time.  And it will slow you down. This is why passwords that may need to be cracked often have only an initial Uppercase.
